# Angular2 Component selector: array like '[ui-components]'

Tags: angular

I've realized sometimes I've seen angular2 code as:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[ui-components]'
```

What does `selector: '[ui-components]` mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means you are making the component as an attribute component instead of an element component. When you use the component in your html, you write

```
<div ui-components></div>
```

if you use

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ui-components' // without the brackets
```

you have to use this notation in your html

```
<ui-components></ui-components>
```

[Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) are some readings from the Angular2 documentation.